# SonicWall TZ 200 Network bandwidth or usage monitoring

Tags: bandwidth, network-monitoring, pfsense, sonicwall

I was using Pfsense for a while and recently replaced it with SonicWall TZ200.

What I miss now is a Bandwidth or usage monitoring like BandwidthD to monitor IP wise traffic. 
How can I do this through SonicWall TZ200 or some other software?
I installed BandwidthD on my local machine. It works perfect, but I doubt that it shows only the traffic from and to my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the specs for the SonicWall TZ200 and it says that it can create Netflow accounting packets. Consequently, any netflow collector. Personally, I've used nTop before and I know it does IP based bandwidth usage , but there are tons of alternatives out there if that doesn't fit your requirements.